# When shift bridging/speedbriding in Minecraft, how much faster is it to bridge at 45 degrees than just bridging forward?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to many Minecraft youtubers and guides, bridging at 45 degrees is much faster than bridging forward normally. How much of an advantage does bridging at 45 degrees give me over bridging forward?

Comment: It's definitely worth doing I don't know how much faster it is but it's not really that much harder you just need to got the right spot. Also do you mean bridging at 45 degrees and pressing W and a/d or going 45 degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's look at this from a basic math problem. Steve wants to walk 8 blocks to the left and 6 blocks up, but he feels there is a more efficient way to do it, instead of walking in two straight lines, as shown below:
[image: Triangle]

He then remembers something called the *Pythagorean Theorem*, which allows him to test the unknown path he believes could be faster, with this equation: (a * a) + (b * b) = (c * c). He then simply replaces a with 8, b with 6, and c with x. Then, after some arithmetic, he finds that the equation breaks down to 100 = (x * x). Then, after finding the square root of each, he finds that x is equal to 10. **By logic, this means that by going in a single path, he can save four blocks of travelling time.** It isn't necessarily a question of 45 degrees, but YouTubers use this mode of travel because it is easier to place blocks quicker at this specific angle.

Comment: Is this actually true? You can't place blocks diagonally floating in the air, so if you go diagonally you still need to place 2 blocks side by side. It would be faster to travel the bridge once it's built, but not during the building itself, which is the important part

Comment: @AJPerez I mean going horizontal, but it still would be less to travel if you were going vertical.

Comment: @AJPerez When shift-bridging your limiting factor is sneaking speed, not placing blocks. Regarding speed, it boils down to shortest path. It's different with god-bridging where your ability to place the blocks accurately in the nick of time is more important.

Comment: @SF. that's true, thanks. Somehow I forgot that the slow part is the crouching, not placing the blocks :)

Answer (score 3):

As per OKProgrammer, diagonal shift-bridging results in shorter path connecting two random points, and the resulting time of crouching through shorter distance is the largest. But this style necessitates walking straight backwards.

Meanwhile, strafing while bridging - standing nearly sideways to your bridging direction - significantly increases your crawling speed - so much that going along two sides of a square is barely slower than bridging along the diagonal.

I've performed a test, timing building the bridge across the diagonal of a 3x3 chunks area:

[image]

Here are the results:

- 1:22 - regular shift-bridging
- 1:04 - strafe shift-bridging
- 0:57 - diagonal bridging

In particular, that means if your path isn't a perfect diagonal, the straight line is not the fastest path. Shift-bridge diagonally at 45 degrees angle to get in line with your destination, then strafe-bridge to your destination, and you'll get there faster than bridging at some other angle.